# RadTreeView not working in IE11 unnecessary firing events

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, telerik

RadTreeView not working in IE11

OnNodeClick event not working in IE11 as in IE9. The system thinks the user is clicking on the Node many times when the user does not. It is firing unnecessary events to the server. What might be the issue?

Framework version 4 and Telerik version Q1 2014

Comment: Show the code. We are not yet equipped with telepathic powers.

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading to the latest (Q1 2015 at the time of writing) and make sure the issue is not with the .NET framework as .NET 4.0 fails to detect IE10 and IE11 and MS AJAX dies: http://blogs.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/posts/13-12-19/how-to-get-your-asp.net-application-working-in-ie11